# Conditional Expectation of a Maximum term of Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am dealing with the follows conditional expectation problem, in which q(t) is the length of queue at time t of a Poisson arrival with rate l. I have done the following calculation. Could anybody confirm that if it is correct, and comment about the next step, please. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I assume $\beta \geq 0$.  If $X$ is a random variable, it looks like you are asking if $$ E[\max\{0, X\}] = P[X \geq 0] E[X | X\geq 0]$$ which is "yes" by the law of total expectation, i.e., $$ E[Max] = E[Max|X \geq 0]P[X\geq 0] + E[Max|X<0]P[X<0]$$

Comment: yes, β≥0. That's great! Can you please help/guide me with the next steps? I am new to this... I am trying to simplify the expectation term further

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do and so I do not know what the next steps would be.

Comment: comment edited, My problem is with the expectation part, would the conditional probability term (the denominator) cancel out the probability term which is multiplied to?

Comment: I do not understand. You cannot just randomly cancel expressions that look similar. Are you asking if $P[X\geq 0]E[X|X\geq 0] = E[X]$?  There is no reason to conclude this.

Comment: Thank you Michael! I have added the whole expression to my question. Would be great if you can hint me how to solve that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69142/discussion-between-13554n-and-michael).

Comment: I do not know how to compute that expectation, unless perhaps if $q(t)$ is in steady state for an M/M/1 queue (which is likely not what you are looking for).  I don't know what $t^*$ is but it looks like you are doing some type of transient analysis, which seems hard.  Some context might help.

Comment: Thanks!! yes it is an $M/M1$ and $t^{*}$ is a given constant..

Comment: What is hte context?  Why do you want to compute that expression?  Is the M/M/1 in "steady state" at time $t$, or is this time $t$ assuming $q(0)=0$?

Comment: Mainly to take derivative of the simplified expression wrt $t$, and other parameters if needed. It is steady state and $q(0)=0$

Comment: What is the ultimate goal?  I ask because it looks like you have an expression related to some estimate of a distribution, or some function of the distribution,  which is useless if you assume steady state and you already have the full distribution.  I also wonder if your $t^*$ is really a constant, or if it depends on the process, such as a time the system was last empty, or seomthign.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to check conditions under which some decision make sense if taken. The simplified expression is needed to be compared with some other expression which is easier than this to compute

Comment: Well you can use that the distirbution of an M/M/1 queue in steady state is $P[Q=k] = (1-\rho)\rho^k$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ and $\rho = \lambda/\mu$, assuming $0 < \rho < 1$.  And $E[Max] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} E[Max|Q=k]P[Q=k]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I deal with the conditional expectations?

Comment: Can you evaluate $E[\max[0, a-Q/s]| Q=5]$? (with $a, s$ constants)

Comment: ... I will try it! Thanks

Comment: Is the answer No?!

Comment: I do not understand your comment above.  Note taht $E[f(X)|X=5]=f(5)$.

Comment: so it should be $Max[0,a-5/s]$ if got it! Thanks for your nice way of teaching!! :)